# Which is the correct way to calculate AUC with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, metrics, auc

I noticed that the result of the following two codes is different.

```
#1
metrics.plot_roc_curve(classifier, X_test, y_test, ax=plt.gca())


#2
metrics.plot_roc_curve(classifier, X_test, y_test, ax=plt.gca(), label=clsname + ' (AUC = %.2f)' % roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predicted))
```

So, which method is correct?

I have added a simple reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = data.data
y = data.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=12)

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='rbf')
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = svclassifier.predict(X_test)

print('AUC = %.2f' % roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predicted))  #1

metrics.plot_roc_curve(svclassifier, X_test, y_test, ax=plt.gca())  #2
plt.show()
```

Output (#1):

```
AUC = 0.86
```

While (#2):

[image]

Comment: @Mr.T I haven't seen that. Should I remove my question?

Comment: Waht is the difference between #1 and #2? you are just adding a label to #2 , refer [plot_roc_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve.html?highlight=sklearn%20metrics%20plot_roc), refer [matplotlib.pyplot. **kwargs label](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label)

Comment: @Shijith I manually add `roc_auc_score ` as a label instead of an automatic legend to show the difference. Could you elaborate on that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here may be sklearn internally using `predict_proba()` to get probabilities of  each class, and from that finding auc

Example , when you are using `classifier.predict()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets, metrics, model_selection, svm
X, y = datasets.make_classification(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
clf = svm.SVC(random_state=0,probability=False)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict(X_test)

>> array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 0])

# calculate auc
metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))

>>>0.8782051282051283  # ~0.88
```

if you use `classifier.predict_proba()`

```
X, y = datasets.make_classification(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
# set probability=True
clf = svm.SVC(random_state=0,probability=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict_proba(X_test)

>> array([[0.13625954, 0.86374046],
       [0.90517034, 0.09482966],
       [0.19754525, 0.80245475],
       [0.96741274, 0.03258726],
       [0.80850602, 0.19149398],
       ......................,
       [0.31927198, 0.68072802],
       [0.8454472 , 0.1545528 ],
       [0.75919018, 0.24080982]])

# calculate auc
# when computing the roc auc metrics, by default, estimators.classes_[1] is   
# considered as the positive class here 'clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]'

metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
>> 0.9102564102564102
```

so for your question `metrics.plot_roc_curve(classifier, X_test, y_test, ax=plt.gca())` may be using default `predict_proba()` to predict the `auc`, and for `metrics.plot_roc_curve(classifier, X_test, y_test, ax=plt.gca(), label=clsname + ' (AUC = %.2f)' % roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predicted))`, you are calculating `roc_auc_score` and passing the score as a label.

Comment: Thanks. I think using `.predict` is more common for research work, right?

Comment: @DavidWs. No, the ROC curve needs predicted probabilities.  Using the hard class prediction is incorrect.